# Finding issue in compiling a query

Tags: android, string

```
 Cursor cursor12 = managedQuery(GroceryListContentProvider.NOTES_URI,
            projection, where, null, null);   


String where="date1>='" + from + "'" + " AND " + "date1<='" + to+ "'";

String[] projection = new String[] {(count(Notes.NOTE_DATE1)),sum(Notes.TOTAL_COST),Notes.NOTE_DATE1};
```

If the cursor contains values like this:

```
2012-03-12       25
2012-03-12       50
2012-07-14       88
```

Then my output should be:

```
2012-03-12(2)    75
2012-07-14(1)    88
```

Is it possible to find the count of the `column_field` using this query?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: is there anyone who can answer me this question??

Comment: why not edit your question... then it will be more clear than comments..

Comment: i have four values in this cursor.i have two same dates.but the output i  shud get shud return me the count for the same dates and also the total cost under that two dates.

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

You should write a loop for the entries of the same date. Build the sum over all Costs for a specific date. Then Start with the next entry you find, and loop until you are finished with all entries. Always compare for same entries and finish when you reach the end.

Comment: "SELECT SUM(total_cost),date1,COUNT(date1) FROM notes"          is'nt it possible to use this query anywhere???

Comment: sorry I can't follow you anymore. Maybe you should edit your Question until everything is clear, or just try an easier approach like I suggested 8)

Comment: i asked cant we use a count or sum function??

Comment: Just make arrays, one for dates, and one for costs and make the sum yourself. With more I cannot help you